# TSQL not committing the transaction, despite executing full code

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access, import

I have an imports program that I have written to delete all the data from all datatables in a SQLServer database, and replace the data with new data from an Access database. The trouble is, is that despite it giving me the message box at the end "Import completed!", the SQLServer data seems to remain the same. I know there is a LOT of code here, apologies for that, but can anybody suggest why the data is not changing?

I thought maybe it was because my delete statements all had to be one transaction, then the inserts a separate one? Am I missing something?

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class dbImports

Public Shared Function importDatabase(con As OleDbConnection, importsCon As OleDbConnection)

    Dim tr As OleDbTransaction = Nothing
    Dim sql As New OleDbCommand

    sql.Connection = con
    sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Try

        tr = con.BeginTransaction()

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblModules"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblContracts"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblContractText"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblEmailSettings"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblIncidents"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblInvoiceLog"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblMailLog"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblModuleNames"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblRecurring"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblSystemSettings"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblContracts ORDER BY ContractID"
        sql.Transaction = tr

        Dim sqlct As String
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim conID As Integer
            Dim custacc As String
            Dim datestart As Object
            Dim daterenew As Object
            Dim fee As Double
            Dim agree As String
            Dim details As String
            Dim datesent As Object
            Dim timesent As Object
            Dim remname As String
            Dim remmail As String

            conID = dr("ContractID")
            custacc = dbToString(dr("CustAcc"))
            datestart = dbToDate(dr("DateStart"))
            daterenew = dbToDate(dr("DateRenew"))
            fee = dr("Fee")
            agree = dbToString(dr("Agreement"))
            details = dbToString(dr("OtherDetails"))
            datesent = dbToDate(dr("DateSent"))
            timesent = dbToTime(dr("TimeSent"))
            remname = dbToString(dr("ReminderName"))
            remmail = dbToString(dr("ReminderEmail"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblContracts(ContractID, CustAcc, DateStart, DateRenew, Fee, Agreement, OtherDetails, DateSent, TimeSent, ReminderName, ReminderEmail) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ContractID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = conID
            sql.Parameters.Add("@CustAcc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = custacc
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateStart", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = datestart
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateRenew", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = daterenew
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Fee", OleDbType.Double).Value = fee
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Agreement", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agree
            sql.Parameters.Add("@OtherDetails", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = details
            sql.Parameters.Add("DateSent", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = datesent
            sql.Parameters.Add("@TimeSent", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = timesent
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ReminderName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = remname
            sql.Parameters.Add("@remmail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = remmail

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblContractText ORDER BY pk"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim Para1 As String
            Dim pk As Integer
            Dim BillPara As String

            Para1 = dbToString(dr("Para1"))
            pk = dr("pk")
            BillPara = dbToString(dr("BillPara"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblContractText(Para1, pk, BillPara) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Para1", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Para1
            sql.Parameters.Add("@pk", OleDbType.Integer).Value = pk
            sql.Parameters.Add("@BillPara", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = BillPara

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblEmailSettings ORDER BY ID"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim ID As String
            Dim PW As String
            Dim Subject As String
            Dim Body As String
            Dim SMTP As String
            Dim conf As Boolean
            Dim invSub As String
            Dim invBody As String

            ID = dbToString(dr("ID"))
            PW = dbToString(dr("PW"))
            Subject = dbToString(dr("Subject"))
            Body = dbToString(dr("Body"))
            SMTP = dbToString(dr("SMTPHost"))
            conf = dbToBoolean(dr("Confirmation"))
            invSub = dbToString(dr("invSubject"))
            invBody = dbToString(dr("invBody"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblEmailSettings(ID, PW, Subject, Body, SMTPHost, Confirmation, invSubject, invBody) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ID
            sql.Parameters.Add("@PW", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PW
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Subject", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Subject
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Body", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Body
            sql.Parameters.Add("@SMTPHost", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = SMTP
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Confimation", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = conf
            sql.Parameters.Add("@invSubject", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = invSub
            sql.Parameters.Add("@invBody", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = invBody

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblIncidents ORDER BY supportID"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim supportID As Integer
            Dim clientName As String
            Dim dateStart As Object
            Dim dateEnd As Object
            Dim incidentProblem As String
            Dim timeStart As Object
            Dim timeEnd As Object
            Dim incidentSolved As Boolean
            Dim incidentSolution As String

            supportID = (dr("supportID"))
            clientName = dbToString(dr("clientName"))
            dateStart = dbToDate(dr("dateStart"))
            dateEnd = dbToDate(dr("dateEnd"))
            incidentProblem = dbToString(dr("incidentProblem"))
            timeStart = dbToTime(dr("timeStart"))
            timeEnd = dbToTime(dr("timeEnd"))
            incidentSolved = dbToBoolean(dr("incidentSolved"))
            incidentSolution = dbToString(dr("incidentSolution"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblIncidents(supportID, clientName, dateStart, dateEnd, incidentProblem, timeStart, timeEnd, incidentSolved, incidentSolution) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@supportID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = supportID
            sql.Parameters.Add("@clientName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = clientName
            sql.Parameters.Add("@dateStart", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dateStart
            sql.Parameters.Add("@dateEnd", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dateEnd
            sql.Parameters.Add("@incidentProblem", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentProblem
            sql.Parameters.Add("@timeStart", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = timeStart
            sql.Parameters.Add("@timeEnd", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = timeEnd
            sql.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolved", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = incidentSolved
            sql.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolution", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentSolution

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblInvoiceLog ORDER BY BatchNumber"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim BatchNumber As Integer
            Dim BatchLine As Integer
            Dim DatePosted As Object
            Dim AccCode As String
            Dim Description As String
            Dim Period As String
            Dim TotalFee As Double

            BatchNumber = dr("BatchNumber")
            BatchLine = dr("BatchLine")
            DatePosted = dbToDate(dr("DatePosted"))
            AccCode = dbToString(dr("AccCode"))
            Description = dbToString(dr("Description"))
            Period = dbToString(dr("Period"))
            TotalFee = dr("TotalFee")

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblInvoiceLog(BatchNumber, BatchLine, DatePosted, AccCode, Description, Period, TotalFee) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@BatchNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = BatchNumber
            sql.Parameters.Add("@BatchLine", OleDbType.Integer).Value = BatchLine
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DatePosted", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DatePosted
            sql.Parameters.Add("@AccCode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AccCode
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Description", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Description
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Period", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Period
            sql.Parameters.Add("@TotalFee", OleDbType.Double).Value = TotalFee

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblMailLog ORDER BY mailID"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim mailID As Integer
            Dim Sender As String
            Dim Receiver As String
            Dim FileName As String
            Dim DateSent As Object
            Dim TimeSent As String
            Dim Body As String
            Dim AccCode As String

            mailID = dr("mailID")
            Sender = dbToString(dr("Sender"))
            Receiver = dbToString(dr("Receiver"))
            FileName = dbToString(dr("FileName"))
            DateSent = dbToDate(dr("DateSent"))
            TimeSent = dbToString(dr("TimeSent"))
            Body = dbToString(dr("Body"))
            AccCode = dbToString(dr("AccCode"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblMailLog(mailID, Sender, Receiver, FileName, DateSent, TimeSent, Body, AccCode) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@mailID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mailID
            sql.Parameters.Add("Sender", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Sender
            sql.Parameters.Add("Receiver", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Receiver
            sql.Parameters.Add("@FileName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateSent", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateSent
            sql.Parameters.Add("@TimeSent", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TimeSent
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Body", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Body
            sql.Parameters.Add("@AccCode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AccCode

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblModuleNames"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim fModule As String

            fModule = dbToString(dr("Module"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblModuleNames(Module) VALUES(?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Module", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fModule

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblModules ORDER BY ModuleID"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim ModuleID As Integer
            Dim ModuleName As String
            Dim NumberUsers As String
            Dim License As String
            Dim Username As String
            Dim ContractID As Integer

            ModuleID = dr("ModuleID")
            ModuleName = dbToString(dr("ModuleName"))
            NumberUsers = dbToString(dr("NumberUsers"))
            License = dbToString(dr("License"))
            Username = dbToString(dr("Username"))
            ContractID = dr("ContractID")

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblModules(ModuleID, ModuleName, NumberUsers, License, Username, ContractID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ModuleID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ModuleID
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ModuleName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ModuleName
            sql.Parameters.Add("@NumberUsers", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NumberUsers
            sql.Parameters.Add("@License", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = License
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Username
            sql.Parameters.Add("ContractID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ContractID

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblRecurring ORDER BY billID"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim billID As Integer
            Dim DateStart As Object
            Dim DateNext As Object
            Dim Fee As Double
            Dim Description As String
            Dim AccountCode As String
            Dim Notes As String

            billID = dr("billID")
            DateStart = dbToDate(dr("DateStart"))
            DateNext = dbToDate(dr("DateNext"))
            Fee = dr("Fee")
            Description = dbToString(dr("Description"))
            AccountCode = dbToString(dr("AccountCode"))
            Notes = dbToString(dr("Notes"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblRecurring(billID, DateStart, DateNext, Fee, Description, AccountCode, Notes) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@billID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = billID
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateStart", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateStart
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateNext", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateNext
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Fee", OleDbType.Double).Value = Fee
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Description", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Description
            sql.Parameters.Add("@AccountCode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AccountCode
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Notes", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Notes

        Next

        sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblSystemSettings ORDER BY ID"
        sql.Transaction = tr
        sqlct = sql.CommandText

        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim ID As Integer
            Dim listContractsX As Integer
            Dim listContractsY As Integer
            Dim invoiceLogX As Integer
            Dim invoiceLogY As Integer
            Dim mailLogX As Integer
            Dim mailLogY As Integer
            Dim recurringX As Integer
            Dim recurringY As Integer
            Dim reportsX As Integer
            Dim reportsY As Integer

            ID = dr("ID")
            listContractsX = dr("listContractsX")
            listContractsY = dr("listContractsY")
            invoiceLogX = dr("invoiceLogX")
            invoiceLogY = dr("invoiceLogY")
            mailLogX = dr("mailLogX")
            mailLogY = dr("mailLogY")
            recurringX = dr("recurringX")
            recurringY = dr("recurringY")
            reportsX = dr("reportsX")
            reportsY = dr("reportsY")

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblSystemSettings(ID, listContractsX, listContractsY, invoiceLogX, invoiceLogY, mailLogX, mailLogY, recurringX, recurringY, reportsX, reportsY) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ID
            sql.Parameters.Add("@listContractsX", OleDbType.Integer).Value = listContractsX
            sql.Parameters.Add("@listContractsY", OleDbType.Integer).Value = listContractsY
            sql.Parameters.Add("@invoiceLogX", OleDbType.Integer).Value = invoiceLogX
            sql.Parameters.Add("@invoiceLogY", OleDbType.Integer).Value = invoiceLogY
            sql.Parameters.Add("@mailLogX", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mailLogX
            sql.Parameters.Add("@mailLogY", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mailLogY
            sql.Parameters.Add("@recurringX", OleDbType.Integer).Value = recurringX
            sql.Parameters.Add("@recurringY", OleDbType.Integer).Value = recurringY
            sql.Parameters.Add("@reportsX", OleDbType.Integer).Value = reportsX
            sql.Parameters.Add("@reportsY", OleDbType.Integer).Value = reportsY

        Next

        tr.Commit()
        MsgBox("Import Completed!")

    Catch ex As Exception

        tr.Rollback()

        Throw
    End Try

End Function

    Public Shared Function getDataTable(ByVal sqlct As String, importsCon As OleDbConnection, tr As OleDbTransaction) As DataTable

    Dim sql As OleDbCommand
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    If tr IsNot Nothing Then
        sql = New OleDbCommand(sqlct, importsCon, tr)
    Else
        sql = New OleDbCommand(sqlct, importsCon)
    End If

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Return dt

End Function
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to do way too many different things with a single `OleDbCommand` object. You are doing a whole bunch of manipulations on the one you've named `sql` but as far as I can see you're not calling `.ExecuteNonQuery` to perform the DELETEs and UPDATEs. And, when trying to re-use the `sql` object for different INSERTs you're not calling `sql.Parameters.Clear` to get rid of the old parameters before `.Add`ing new ones.

Comment: @GordThompson So I should create a new `OleDbCommand` for each DELETE/INSERT? Or will calling `.ExecuteNonQuery` after each one do it?

Comment: Calling `.ExecuteNonQuery` is all that's really required, and simply updating the `.CommandText` and calling `.ExecuteNonQuery` is sufficient for the DELETEs. However, consider using a separate `OleDbCommand` object for each INSERT loop and investigate the `.Prepare` method to improve the efficiency of your code when performing repetitive insert operations.

Comment: @GordThompson call it after each DELETE statement? Then set `.CommandText` to "" before setting it again? I'll read up on `.Prepare`, too

Comment: Yes, after you update the `CommandText` with a new `DELETE ...` statement you need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` to actually perform the operation. It is not necessary to set the `CommandText` to `""` before setting it to the next `DELETE ...` statement.

Comment: @GordThompson Okay, the `ExecuteNonQuery` problem fixed the main issue. When creating a new `OleDbCommand` for each INSERT, will I need a new string variable too? (ie, sqlct), or is this okay to just use the same one for, to pass the command into `getDataTable`?

Comment: Re-engineer your code, and let every transaction (update/insert/delete) in a separate command in a separate method. You can Create class with all these methods. In that way you can debug your code and unit test it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each CommandText, you must explicitly call the `ExecuteNonQuery` function so that that command executes in the Database.

Example:

```
sql.Parameters.Clear
sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblModules"
sql.Transaction = tr
sql.ExecuteNonQuery()

sql.Parameters.Clear
sql.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblContracts"
sql.Transaction = tr
sql.ExecuteNonQuery()

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the delete statements are not running since your data remains unchanged. Are you sure your connecting to the database correctly?
This is what I usually do:

```
Using sqlCon as new sqlConnection(sqlConString)
    Using sqlCmd as new sqlCommand("DELETE FROM tbl", slqCon)
       If sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery > 0 Then
          //Delete successful. Import new data.
       End If
    End Using
End Using
```

You can try this to easily delete data from all tables instead of defining each one. Use this ONLY if your going to delete data from all tables under the database.

**EDIT:** Since you're already passing the connection.

```
    Using sqlCmd as new sqlCommand("DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
                                    SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM ?'
                                    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @SQL", con)
       //con.Open If you haven't opened it through another method.
       If sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery > 0 Then
          //Delete successful. Import new data.
       End If
    End Using
```

Comment: Yes, I've checked my connections, both say open, with the correct path (which is read from an ini file, so in any case if it didn't work it would throw and error). So, using this code, where would I put it?

Comment: Under importDatabase. Comment out your delete statements first then make sure that you change sqlConString to your own connection string.

Comment: I'm already passing in the connnection strings when calling the class, will I still have to do it again?

Comment: If you've already opened the connection before running the importDatabase function, you can try the edit I did.